# Conditionally use onFieldSubmitted property of Autocomplete widgets' fieldViewBuilder?

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I want to call a database function from fieldViewBuilder onFieldSubmitted property based on the optionsList like below.

```
class MyAutocomplete extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> holidayNamesList;
  final Future<void> Function({required String selectedName}) setSelectedHoliday;

  MyAutocomplete(
      {Key? key, required this.holidayNamesList, required this.setSelectedHoliday})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyAutocomplete> createState() => _MyAutocompleteState();
}

class _MyAutocompleteState extends State<MyAutocomplete> {
  int? optionsLength;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Autocomplete<String>(
    optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue value) {
      return widget.holidayNamesList
        .where((element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(value.text.toLowerCase()));
  },
    optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, myList) {
      optionsLength = myList.length;
      //......return code here
    }
    fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller, node, onFieldSubmitted) {
      return TextFormField(
      onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
          onFieldSubmitted();
          if(optionsLength == 0) widget.setSelectedHoliday(selectedName: value); // <-- SEE THIS
        },
      // ..... rest of the code here
      )
    }
  )
}
```

But when I print the value of optionsLength from fieldViewBuilder it just picks the initial length and does not update after that, while typing. How to solve this? Any other methods are also appreciated.

Comment: Could someone please explain that why optionsViewBuilder function does NOT re-runs when we type in the field. Because adding a print(myList.length) in there does not give anything in console after first time?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html